# No compatible divices on my beta apps

Tags: android

I don't understand why, I just try to push a beta version on google play and I have no compatible devices on this version (look at the screenshot). So when I download the apps, it's install me the current production version but not the beta like expected.

I have no problem to install it on my devices on dev mod with android studio so I know that this app working on my phone.

Someone can help me ? Thanks

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.lgondor.simpledice"
    >
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera2.full" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.sensor.accelerometer" />
    <supports-screens
        android:smallScreens="true"
        android:normalScreens="true"
        android:largeScreens="true"
        android:xlargeScreens="true">
    </supports-screens>
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/icon_small_shadow"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name="com.lgondor.simpledice.MainActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="com.lgondor.simpledice.AddCustomDiceActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="com.lgondor.simpledice.ManageSwitchActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent" />
        <service android:name="com.lgondor.simpledice.services.WearService">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.gms.wearable.MESSAGE_RECEIVED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

[image]